How to force `systemctl show --all *` to list all units and instances?
I use systemctl show --all * to list all systemd units and all instances with their states.
On some machines it works properly. On other machines it only lists units with a LoadError property.
Example output from one machine:
# systemctl show --no-pager * --property=Id --property=LoadError
Id=int.service
LoadError=org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit "Unit int.service not found."

Id=iptables.txt.service
LoadError=org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit "Unit iptables.txt.service not found."

(Only two units returned with "strange" names, seems like typos. But systemctl list-units works properly.)
Is it a bug or a feature? Where is this behavior documented? How can I force systemctl show to list all units and instances?

Are you running that with * unquoted? It will be expanded by the shell to all non-hidden files and subdirectories in the current directory

@muru You are right :), thanks!

Your shell is expanding *, so systemctl is given a list of the files in the current directory.
You need to escape it:
systemctl show --all '*'


Yes, thank you, I forgot to escape '*' :)
(But systemctl --all does not list all properties. systemctl list-unit-files does not list all instances. Only systemctl show --all '*' does.)

PS: You are missing show. Your example systemctl --all '*' fails with Unknown command verb *..
